# Integral of exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I have the expected value of the square of the position operator given as

$$\langle x^{2} \rangle= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2}e^{\frac{amx^{2}}{h}}dx$$

I understand that the integrand can only be evaluated by the form 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2} e^{-ax^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^{3}}}$$

but it does not yield the correct answer to my solution sheet.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are $a, m, h$ constant? Their product is less than 0?

Comment: It might be good to know what the answer of your solution sheet is.

Comment: I suppose that $am/h$ is negative. If not the integral would be not convergent. Then, use the given formula in which $a$ must be remplaced by $|am/h|$.

Comment: I guess there is typo, it should be $e^{-\frac{amx^2}{h}}$ in the intergral, if that is the case then as JJacquelin has mentioned you just need to replace a by corresponding constant.

Comment: @mickepIt worked out!. It was a typo in the question.